# Mixture of negative binomial distributions (technically some of them are geometric)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, inclusion-exclusion, coupon-collector

I have something that I am trying to compute.

Let's say that a number is uniformly generated 1-4.

What would be the expected number of generations required to get at least 3 1s and every other number was generated at least once.

I know how to calculate at least 3 1s as that would be a negative binomial distribution with p=3/4 and r=3.

I know how to calculate at least every number shows up once, since those are geometric distrubutions (or negative binomial with r=1).

How can I marry these concepts to come up with an expected value?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. Please see [this tutorial and reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) on how to typeset math on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a generalized [coupon collector's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem). Two approaches you can take to this are used in the two answers at [Coupon Collecting Problem: $4$ coupons with $p_1 = p_2 = \frac{1}{8}$ and $p_3 = p_4 = \frac{3}{8}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2921853).

In the spirit of Ross's answer, you can define a state $(j,k)$ with $0\le j,k\le3$, in which you've generated $j$ $1$s and $k$ of the other numbers at least once. Then the expected number $a_{jk}$ of remaining generations satisfies the recurrence

$$
a_{jk}=1+\frac14a_{j+1,k}+\frac k4a_{jk}+\frac{3-k}4a_{j,k+1}\;,
$$

where the indices aren't incremented beyond $3$ and the initial value is $a_{33}=0$. The result is

\begin{array}{c|cccc}
j\setminus k&0&1&2&3\\\hline
0&\frac{1915}{144}&\frac{349}{27}&\frac{25}2&12\\
1&\frac{125}{12}&\frac{88}9&9&8\\
2&\frac{25}3&\frac{22}3&6&4\\
3&\frac{22}3&6&4&0\\
\end{array}

Thus the expected number of generations is $a_{00}=\frac{1915}{144}\approx13.3$.

In the spirit of my answer, we can apply [inclusion–exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) to the four conditions $A_i$ that you've generated $i$ a sufficient number of times ($3$ for $i=1$ and $1$ otherwise). Let $N_i$ denote the number of generations required until $A_i$ is fulfilled, and let $N=\max_iN_i$ denote the number of generations required until all the conditions $A_i$ are fulfilled. Then

\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathsf E[N]
&=&
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\mathsf P(N\gt n)
\\
&=&
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\mathsf P\left(\bigvee_{i\in\{1,2,3,4\}}N_i\gt n\right)
\\
&=&
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{\emptyset\ne S\subseteq\{1,2,3,4\}}(-1)^{|S|+1}\mathsf P\left(\bigwedge_{i\in S}N_i\gt n\right)\;.
\end{eqnarray*}

Now there are two cases. If $1\notin S$, we have

$$
\mathsf P\left(\bigwedge_{i\in S}N_i\gt n\right)=4^{-n}(4-|S|)^n\;.
$$

If $1\in S$, we have

$$
\mathsf P\left(\bigwedge_{i\in S}N_i\gt n\right)=\sum_{j=0}^2\binom nj4^{-n}(4-|S|)^{n-j}\;.
$$

Splitting the sum over $S$ into these two cases, we obtain

\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{\emptyset\ne S\subseteq\{2,3,4\}}(-1)^{|S|+1}\mathsf P\left(\bigwedge_{i\in S}N_i\gt n\right)
&=&
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^3(-1)^{k+1}\binom3k4^{-n}(4-k)^n
\\
&=&
\sum_{k=1}^3(-1)^{k+1}\binom3k\frac4k
\\
&=&
12-6+\frac43
\\
&=&
\frac{22}3
\end{eqnarray*}

and

\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{S\subseteq\{2,3,4\}}(-1)^{|S|}\mathsf P\left(\bigwedge_{i\in S\cup\{1\}}N_i\gt n\right)
&=&
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{j=0}^2\sum_{k=0}^3(-1)^k\binom3k\binom nj4^{-n}(4-(k+1))^{n-j}
\\
&=&
4\sum_{j=0}^2\sum_{k=0}^3(-1)^k\binom3k\left(\frac1{k+1}\right)^{j+1}
\\
&=&
12-4\left(\frac32-1+\frac14+\frac34-\frac13+\frac1{16}+\frac38-\frac19+\frac1{64}\right)
\\
&=&
\frac{859}{144}\;.
\end{eqnarray*}

Together, this is

$$
\frac{22}3+\frac{859}{144}=\frac{1915}{144}\approx13.3\;,
$$

in agreement with the first result.

Comment: Nicely done... I agree for this question Ross M's approach is easier to digest...  for me personally the notation necessary in the second approach takes a lot of mental effort to comprehend, I know you're solving the terms in inclusion exclusion but unfortunately my brain is like a 30 horsepower lawn mower. Question for you... when coming up with the 4 by 4 table with all the states in the Ross M approach do you use a scripting language? If so can you share which one?

Comment: @HJ_beginner: Actually, in this case I did it by hand :-). If it had been $4$ instead of $3$, I would have coded it in Java. I often include links to Java code I use in my answers.

Comment: Ah thanks for sharing. In regards to the second approach this notation was bizarre to me $\emptyset\ne S\subseteq\{1,2,3,4\}$ but I see on the wiki page you linked it's a compact way to express the inclusion exclusion formula. Great answer with two approaches and I enjoyed OP's question. There's so many variations of coupon collecting it's obscene but they remind me of collecting rare items in video games so very relevant to today.

Comment: This was actually to solve the expected number of ultra jumps I would do on Super Mario RPG. Video games, indeed. Thank you so much for this answer.

Comment: @swinch That is an excellent game. Good taste.

Comment: I had made a python script that estimated this result and I got basically 13.2985, but I figured there had to be an elegant solution. I really like the recurrence relation way as I think it is very digestible.  Here's the relevance of this answer:  https://pastebin.com/7ghExJR6

Comment: @swinch Thanks for sharing your article and python script. It's been years since I beat the Axem Rangers lol. Also per this particular site if you found joriki's answer "good" you should accept it

Answer (score 0):

Here’s yet another way to obtain the solution, using “Poissonization”. Instead of generating numbers at discrete times, consider $4$ independent Poisson processes with rate $1$, one for each number.

The interarrival times of a Poisson process are independently geometrically distributed, so at time $t$ the probability that a given process has generated its number is $1-\mathrm e^{-t}$ and the probability that the process that generates $1$s has generated three $1$s is given by the cumulative distribution function $1-\mathrm e^{-t}\left(1+t+\frac12t^2\right)$ of an [Erlang-$3$ distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function_(CDF)), the distribution of the sum of $3$ independent identically geometrically distributed variables. The sum of the $4$ Poisson processes is itself a Poisson process, with rate $4$. As shown in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3454032), the expected number of number generations required is equal to number of generations expected to occur in the expected time required, which in this case yields

$$
4\int_0^\infty\left(1-\left(1-\mathrm e^{-t}\right)^3\left(1-\mathrm e^{-t}\left(1+t+\frac12t^2\right)\right)\right)\mathrm dt=\frac{1915}{144}\;,
$$

in agreement with the other two approaches.